# Two ways to find the cosine of 180 degree angle

Tags: trigonometry

I found a question how to find the value of cos 180, then we all know that its answer is equal to cos 0, which give us 1 as answer. I myself think that the idea of cos 180 is equal to 1 is :

```
cos 180 = cos(180 - 0) 
cos 180 = -cos 0        "which is cos(180-a) =- cos a"
cos 180 =- 1.          

cos 180 = cos(270-90) 
cos 180 = -sin 90      cos(270-a) = -sin a, 
cos 180 = -1
```

Comment: $\cos 180^\circ \neq \cos 0^\circ$. Think about it in terms of the unit circle to see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second line you are using $\cos(A-B)=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B$ but the problem is that you are implying $\cos180=1$ ($\sin180=0$ so that part cancels) to end up with the result $\cos180=1$, which makes your proof "correct", but obviously is incorrect.

There are lots more examples where an incorrect assumption while using a correct identity can make you "prove" that assumption to be true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for my wrong formula, I've found that :

```
 cos 180 = cos (180-0) = -cos 0 = -1 (method 1)
 cos 180 = cos (270-90) = -sin 90 = -1 (method 2)
```

Thanks to semiclassical, and other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This implication

$\begin{align}\cos 180^\circ & = \cos(180^\circ - 0) \\
\cos 180^\circ & = \cos 0\end{align}$

is simply **FALSE**, the reasoning like this would work for sine, but for cosine you have

$\cos 180^\circ = -\cos(180^\circ - 180^\circ) = -\cos(0) = -1$

Answer (score -1):

cos180 = cos(90+90)
Using cos(A+B) = cosAcosB-sinAsinB

cos(90+90) = cos90cos90-sin90sin90

```
       = 0*0-1*1

       =-1
```

therefore, cos180 = -1

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).